# Is there a way to turn off tree shaking when I build a flutter for web app with the "Flutter build web" command?

Tags: flutter, dart2js, dart-dev-compiler

I am trying to put  a prototype of my flutter app on the web so I can show it to some people but in release mode some features are broken while in debug mode they are not.
  I want to turn off tree-shaking to see if that might be causing the trouble.
  So, is there a way to turn off tree shaking when I build a flutter-for-web app with the "Flutter build web" command?
Maybe a build.yaml specifying dartdevc, or a dart2js option?  What would that look like?  I tried the following build.yaml but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:        
        options:
          compiler: dartdevc
```